# MySql check if a value is different from a value in a database

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to check if a value inserted into a taxtbox is different from a value listed on a database.

for now i have this code:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['search'];
$sql_res=mysql_query("select name, surname, test, from table where name like '%$q%' or surname like '%$q%' order by field (test,1,0)");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$name=$row['name'];
$surname=$row['surname'];
$test=$row['test'];

$b_name='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$b_surname='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$final_name = str_ireplace($q, $b_name, $surname);
$final_surname = str_ireplace($q, $b_name, $surname);
                
$display = '<div> HTML code here</div>';
    
?>

<?php echo $display?>

    
<?php

}
}
    if($final_name != $name){$display = "no";}

?>
```

and using this code, if the value exist everything works fine, otherwise i have this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\A\search.php on line 44
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: final_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\A\search.php on line 44

any help?

**EDIT:**

Ok, i think that maybe the problem is the live search..
i mean, with your help i can show a message if the `$q != $name` but the problem is that this message is always visible at the bottom of the results, and as long as there's no more match, the results disappears and the message is above everything.

I think that maybe just because the search is live, the textbox value is never equal to the database one.

Is it correct?

Comment: Variables name, final_name and display are outside the while loop, where they were defined.

Comment: `$name` only exists if your query didn't fail. `$final_name` is not defined anywhere in the code excerpt posted.

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension (supplying the mysql_ functions) has been deprecated since 2012, in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$check = mysql_num_rows($sql_res);
if($check > 0) {
  // your while loop and other code
}
```

**Note** :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

or try to check `empty()` or i`sset()` for check values exist

```
$name=(!empty($row['name']) ? $row['name'] : '');
// and also for other vars same process
```